# Are my cannellini beans safe?

Tags: food-safety, beans, canning, botulism

I've never cooked with these before, si maybe I'm just being paranoid, but I was kinda surprised when I opened my (store bought) can of beans and found that the liquid they were packed in was kinda cloudy. I've heard that this can be a sign of botulism. The can is not dented or bulging, and they don't smell bad. It seems like the beans just dissolved a bit into the liquid, and this is why the liquid is kinda starchy and slimy, but it seemed worth asking... Anyone have experience opening canned cannellini beans? Is it normal for the liquid to be clouded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is normal for store bought canned beans to have a cloudy liquid. This applies to previously dried, starchy beans such as cannellini, kidney, etc.

The water will get cloudy also when you cook dried beans.

For others like green string beans or wax beans you would expect to see a clear liquid.

Comment: Thank you! Seemed ok, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @AgentWiggles I've heard that the liquid can even be used as a vegetarian substitute for egg white.

Comment: Yeah, if you add a pinch of cream of tarter and some salt and vanilla extract and whip it up, you can make meringues ; you can find recipes if you search aquafaba.

Comment: @Random832 vegetarian -> vegan, no? (Vegetarians eat eggs)